# locally compact metric space is completely metrizable

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to prove

> any locally compact metric space is completely metrizable

I thought it suffices to prove the metric space is complete, but then I found $(0,1)$ with the standard topology is a counter example. Therefore, I need to construct a different metric that is complete.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Isn't $(0,1)$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$? We can even find an explicit homeomorphism $f: (0, 1)\to \mathbb{R}$ where $f(x)=\dfrac{x-1/2}{x(x-1)}.$

Comment: @Bumblebee It is. But $1/n$ is Cauchy, but does not have limit in $(0,1)?$

Comment: Yes, but $\mathbb{R}$ is complete. So, still $(0,1)$ is completely metrizable.

Comment: Then (0,1) is locally compact but not complete? This serves as a counter example? @Bumblebee

Comment: @Bumblebee Sure. That counter example is for "locally compact metric space is complete".

Comment: But how can I construct a complete metric for locally compact metric space? @Bumblebee

Comment: Sure. See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/151026/locally-compact-space-that-is-not-topologically-complete#:~:text=It%20is%20know%20that%20for,metric%20spaces%20are%20topologically%20complete.) for a solution to your question. However $\mathbb{Q}$ is completely metrizable and not locally compact. Therefore converse of your claim is false.

Comment: @Bumblebee: $\mathbb{Q}$ is not completely metrizable.  $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ is, however, so that would work.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Thank you very much for the correction. In fact, $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ equip with the product metric is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}.$ See [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/irrational+number#continued_fractions) for a proof of this last fact.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\langle X,d\rangle$ be a locally compact metric space. Let $\langle\tilde X,\tilde d\rangle$ be its completion. Use the fact that $X$ is locally compact to show that $X$ is open in $\tilde X$ and hence completely metrizable as a $G_\delta$ subset of a complete metric space.